# how to configure browser in sahi when using java

Tags: java, exception, sahi

### I want use java to write sahi script ,in Official website

```
String browserType = "firefox";
    Browser b = new Browser(browserType);
    b.open();
```

### but when I run it  it's has exception as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/ast/NodeVisitor
    at sahi.SahiDriver.main(SahiDriver.java:8)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mozilla.javascript.ast.NodeVisitor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I think maybe I configure a wrong config, caused can't find browser,but i don't know how to do it

Comment: Looks like you miss a jar in your classpath which contains `org.mozilla.javascript.ast.NodeVisitor`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **extlib** folder in which Sahi is installed. Open **rhino** folder in which you will find **js.jar**. Add this jar file in your project's buildpath.